# Unique constraint on column values for rows which have same value on another column

Tags: postgresql

Let `sample_table` be the following `postgres 9.6.6` table:

```
CREATE TABLE sample_table (
    col_a integer,
    col_b integer
);
```

Is it possible to add constraints to `sample_table` to ensure that, on every one of its rows with `col_b=42`, no value on `col_a` appears twice?

Comment: And for rows with `col_b <> 42` there should be no constraint?

Comment: @joop yes, precisely

Comment: Then you could add a conditional index (which can **not** be converted to a constraint, but works *as if*) `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ON sample_table(col_a) WHERE col_b=42;` (and I would prefer col_a to be NOT NULLable)

Comment: @joop thanks, that solves it! Would you like to answer the question?

Comment: There you go ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a *conditional* index (which can **not** be converted to a constraint, but works *as if*):

```
 CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ON sample_table(col_a)
 WHERE col_b=42;
```

I would prefer col_a to be NOT NULL*able*